# InvalidArgumentError: Reduction axis 0 is empty in shape [0]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

**Image classification by implementing googLeNet**
I'm trying to implement GoogLeNet deep convolutional neural network architecture. But when I'm trying to train the model I got InvalidArgumentError: Reduction axis 0 is empty in shape [0] error.

```
for image, label in train_ds.take(1):
print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
print("Label: ", label.numpy())
```

the error occurs by the above code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
import pathlib

from google.colab import drive

# Accessing My Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/CNN'

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
batch_size = 32
img_height = 300
img_width = 300
epochs = 3

def get_data_filenames():
    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_dir+"/dataset_1/*.jpg")
    val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_dir+"/pred/*.jpg",shuffle=False,seed=1)
    test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_dir+"/test_dataset_1/*.jpg",shuffle=False,seed=1)
    return train_ds,val_ds,test_ds


def get_class_names(data_dir):
    data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
    class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('seg_train/*') ]))
    return class_names


def decode_img(img):
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])


def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  class_names = get_class_names(data_dir)
  one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
  return tf.argmax(one_hot)


def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label


def load_data():
    train_ds,val_ds,test_ds = get_data_filenames()
    train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    test_ds = test_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    return train_ds,val_ds,test_ds 


def configure_for_performance(ds):
  ds = ds.cache()
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  return ds


def inception_module(x_inp,kernel_size):
    print("\n*** inception  start ***\n")
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size['x1'], 1, strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x_inp)
    x1 = tf.keras.activations.relu(x1, alpha=0.01)
    print("x1: " , x1.shape)

    x1_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size['x1_3'], 1, strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x_inp)
    x1_3 = tf.keras.activations.relu(x1_3, alpha=0.01)
    print("x1_3: " ,x1_3.shape)
    x3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size['x3'], 3, strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x1_3)
    x3 = tf.keras.activations.relu(x3, alpha=0.01)
    print("x3: ", x3.shape)

    x1_5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size['x1_5'], 1,strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x_inp)
    x1_5 = tf.keras.activations.relu(x1_5, alpha=0.01)
    print("x1_5: ",x1_5.shape)
    x5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size['x5'], 5,strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x1_5)
    x5 = tf.keras.activations.relu(x5, alpha=0.01)
    print("x5: ",x5.shape)

    x_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding='same')(x_inp)
    print("x_pool: ",x_pool.shape)
    x_pool_proj = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size['x_pool_proj'],1,strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x_pool)
    x_pool_proj = tf.keras.activations.relu(x_pool_proj, alpha=0.01)
    print("x_pool_proj: ",x_pool_proj.shape)

    x_out = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x1, x3, x5, x_pool_proj])
    print("x_out: ",x_out.shape)
    print("\n*** inception  end ***\n")

    return x_out


def bell_module(x_inp,i):
    print("\n*** bell start ***\n")
    #bellAvgPool1
    y = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5, strides=3, padding='valid')(x_inp)
    print("avgPool: ",y.shape)

    #bellDropout1
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.4)(y)

    #conv1
    y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 1, strides=1,padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(y)
    print("conv1: ",y.shape)

    #bellfcLayer
    # extra fc layer added in this usecase
    y = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(y)
    print("input: ", y.shape)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(y)
    y = tf.keras.activations.relu(y, alpha=0.01)
    print("fc1: ", y.shape)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(y)
    y = tf.keras.activations.relu(y, alpha=0.01)
    print("fc2: ", y.shape)
    y_out1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',name="bell"+i)(y)
    print("fc3 output : ", y_out1.shape)
    print("\n*** bell  end ***\n")
    return y_out1



def googlenet_dev():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(img_height,img_width,3))
    print("input: ", inputs.shape)

    #conv1
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 7, strides=2,padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(inputs)
    print("conv1: " ,x.shape)
    x = tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.01)

    #maxPool1
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    print("maxPool1: ", x.shape)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    #conv2
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(192, 1, strides=1,padding='valid',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    print("conv2: ", x.shape)
    x = tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.01)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    #conv3
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(192, 3, strides=2,padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    x = tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.01)
    print("conv3: ", x.shape)

    #3a
    kernel_size ={'x1':64,'x1_3':96,'x3':128,'x1_5':16,'x5':32,'x_pool_proj':32}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 3a: ",x.shape)

    #3b
    kernel_size ={'x1':128,'x1_3':128,'x3':192,'x1_5':32,'x5':96,'x_pool_proj':64}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 3b: ",x.shape)

    #maxPool2
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    print("maxPool2: ", x.shape)

    #4a
    kernel_size ={'x1':192,'x1_3':96,'x3':208,'x1_5':16,'x5':48,'x_pool_proj':64}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 4a: ",x.shape)

    y1_out = bell_module(x,"1")

    #4b
    kernel_size ={'x1':160,'x1_3':112,'x3':224,'x1_5':24,'x5':64,'x_pool_proj':64}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 4b: ",x.shape)

    #4c
    kernel_size ={'x1':128,'x1_3':128,'x3':256,'x1_5':24,'x5':64,'x_pool_proj':64}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 4c: ",x.shape)

    #4d
    kernel_size ={'x1':112,'x1_3':144,'x3':288,'x1_5':32,'x5':64,'x_pool_proj':64}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 4d: ",x.shape)

    y2_out = bell_module(x,"2")

    #4e
    kernel_size ={'x1':256,'x1_3':160,'x3':320,'x1_5':32,'x5':128,'x_pool_proj':128}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 4e: ",x.shape)

    #maxPool2
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=7, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    print("maxPool3: ", x.shape)


    #5a
    kernel_size ={'x1':256,'x1_3':160,'x3':320,'x1_5':32,'x5':128,'x_pool_proj':128}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 5a: ",x.shape)

    #5b
    kernel_size ={'x1':384,'x1_3':192,'x3':384,'x1_5':48,'x5':128,'x_pool_proj':128}
    x= inception_module(x,kernel_size)
    print("inception 5b: ",x.shape)

    #avgPool
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=7, strides=1, padding='valid')(x)
    print("avgPool1: ", x.shape)

    #dropout
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.4)(x)

    #fcLayer
    # extra fc layer added in this usecase
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    print("input: ", x.shape)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    x = tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.01)
    print("fc1: ", x.shape)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    x = tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.01)
    print("fc2: ", x.shape)
    x_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',name ="main_bell")(x)
    print("fc3 output: ", x_out.shape)

    googlenet = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=[y1_out,y2_out,x_out])
    return googlenet


def plot_graph(metric_type):
    plt.plot(history.history['main_bell_'+metric_type])
    plt.plot(history.history['bell2_'+metric_type])
    plt.plot(history.history['bell1_'+metric_type])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_main_bell_'+metric_type])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_bell2_'+metric_type])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_bell1_'+metric_type])
    plt.title('model '+metric_type)
    plt.ylabel(metric_type)
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['main_bell_'+metric_type,'bell2_'+metric_type,'bell1_'+metric_type,'val_main_bell_'+metric_type,'val_bell2_'+metric_type,'val_bell1_'+metric_type], loc='lower right')
    plt.show()

def main():
    train_ds,val_ds,test_ds = load_data()
    print("training data size",tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds).numpy())
    print("validation data size",tf.data.experimental.cardinality(val_ds).numpy())
    print("test data size",tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_ds).numpy())

    for image, label in train_ds.take(1):
      print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
      print("Label: ", label.numpy())

    train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds)
    val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds)
    test_ds = configure_for_performance(test_ds)

    googlenet = googlenet_dev()
    googlenet.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
        learning_rate=tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate=0.001, decay_steps=439, decay_rate=0.5, staircase=False), beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
        name='Adam'),
        loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=['accuracy'])

    #history = googlenet.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds)
    history = googlenet.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=3)

    plot_graph('accuracy')
    plot_graph('loss')

    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(googlenet, "googleNet_compuationc_graph.png")

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

When I'm training the model I got this error

/

```
usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Reduction axis 0 is empty in shape [0]
     [[node ArgMax (defined at <ipython-input-9-767fea45370b>:263) ]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_43527]
```

Comment: Can you include the whole traceback?